# Need help with matrix multiplication: $ (aI + bJ)(cI + dJ) $.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

Consider the matrix
$$
A = \left[ \matrix{a & -b \\ b & a} \right],
$$
and write this as $ A = aI + bJ $, where
$$
I = \left[ \matrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1} \right] \quad \text{and} \quad
J = \left[ \matrix{0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0} \right].
$$

(a) Using $ IJ = JI $, compute $ (aI + bJ)(cI + dJ) $.

(b) Compare this with the multiplication of two complex numbers $ a + bi $ and $ c + di $, where $ a $, $ b $, $ c $ and $ d $ are real numbers.

Comment: The equalities $IJ=JI$, $I^2=I$ and $J^2=-I$ are basically all you need to use.

Answer (score 4):

First, note that $I^2=I$ and $J^2=-I$. Now we compute
$$(aI+bJ)(cI+dJ)=(ac-bd)I+ (ad+bc)J.$$
We have $(a+bi)(c+di)= (ac-bd).1+ (ad+bc).i$, moreover $1^2=1$ and $i^2=-1$ so it's clear that the matrices $I$ and $J$ have the same properties of complex numbers $1$ and $i$, Indeed we can establish easily that 
$$\mathrm{span}(I,J)\sim \mathbb{C},$$
where $\sim$ means isomorphism of vector spaces

Answer (score 2):

(a) $(aI+bJ)(cI+dJ) = (aI)(cI) + (aI)(dJ) + (bJ)(cI) + (bJ)(dJ) = acI + adIJ + bcJI - bdI = acI  +(ad+bc)IJ - bdI$